# Repeat rows values in a cross-tab report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a cross tab report which displays month, leave types, and its total per month, Im having trouble repeating row fields
Example for Department named 'Dep1' , here's the sample output:

```
Department             Absenses   Holiday    OFF
  Dep1        January     5          5        5
              February    5          1        5
              Total       10         6        10
```

I need to repeat the Dep1 value all through out the months, for example:

```
Department            Absenses   Holiday    OFF
Dep1          January    5          5        5
Dep1          February   5          1        5
              Total      10         6        10
```

Any trick how to repeat row values in a crystal report, crosstab?

Comment: I tried to customize style and checked "Repeat Row Labels" but it still didnt repeat Dep1

Comment: Is department group 1 and monthy group 2 in cross tab?

Comment: Department is 1st column, the Month is 2nd column @Siva

Comment: Is it compulsory that column 1 should be department and column2 to be month or its fine if you can swipe both

Comment: @Siva yes it is compulsary to have Department in column1 and the month on column2

Comment: Actually tried but unable to find the solution...In cross tab column on will be grouped and column 2 will be according to column 1 hence column will come only 1 per group.. so inorder to get the Department for every month one solution that I can think of is to swipe the columns... take month first and department next.

Answer (score 0):

was able solve my problem by creating a formula for Department + Month number (included month number in the query) and then I used that formula in the crosstab and choose the Department as my existing field